# Laravel/Eloquent - How to query a for a relation that depends on another relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**The query I want to write:**

I have three models:

- A `Chef` hasMany `FoodItem`s.
- A `FoodItem` hasMany `FoodItemAvailabilityDays`.

In my query I want to look up a chef by a given slug. I want to return all of the chef's food items that are available on a specific date.

[image]

**Example:**

Imagine the Chef with slug "bob-smith" sells three food items: Lasagne, Burger and Burrito.

1. The Lasagne is available on 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-02
2. The Burger is available on 2022-01-02
3. The Burrito is available on 2022-01-03

IF I pass in the slug "bob-smith" and the date "2022-01-02"

THEN the query should return the "bob-smith" chef with the Lasange and Burger food items.

**Model relationships:**

```php
// Chef.php
class Chef extends Model
{
  public function foodItems()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(FoodItem::class);
  }
}
```

```php
// FoodItem.php
class FoodItem extends Model
{
  public function availabilityDays()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(FoodItemAvailabilityDay::class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an/the answer

```php
$chef = Chef::where('slug', $slug)
      ->with(['foodItems' => function ($food_item_query) use ($selected_date) {
        $food_item_query->whereHas('availabilityDays', function ($day_query) use ($selected_date) {
          $day_query->where('date', $selected_date);
        });
      }])
      ->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define [a `HasManyThrough` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) between `Chef` and `FoodItemAvailabilityDays` like this:

```php
class Chef extends Model
{
  public function foodItems()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(FoodItem::class);
  }

  public function foodItemAvailabilityDays()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(FoodItemAvailabilityDays::class, Chef::class);
  }
}

class FoodItem extends Model
{
  public function chef()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Chef::class);
  }

  public function availabilityDays()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(FoodItemAvailabilityDay::class);
  }
}

class FoodItemAvailabilityDay extends Model
{
  public function foodItems()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(FoodItem::class);
  }
}
```

Now you can query the relationship directly:

```php
$chef = Chef::whereSlug($slug)
    ->with(['foodItemAvailabilityDays' => fn($q) => $q->where('date', $selectedDate)])
    ->firstOrFail();
```